# How to filter table with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, html-table

I want to filter the table below by a basic text input and using a multiple select field.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bghouse/6by1f9cx/

```
<form class="job-search-form">
    <input class="search-keyword" type="text" placeholder="Enter job title or keyword">
</form>

<label for="search-category search-select">
    <select name="select-category" class="select-category" multiple style="width: 100%;" id="search-category">
        <option value="Engineering - Software">Engineering - Software</option>
        <option value="Engineering - Hardware">Engineering - Hardware</option>
        <option value="Sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
        <option value="Tech Support">Tech Support</option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" class="arrow"></a>
</label>

<table class="job-posts-table" role="grid">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row" class="tablesorter-headerRow">
            <th class="col1 tablesorter-header">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Job Title</div>
            </th>
            <th class="col2 tablesorter-header">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Category</div>
            </th>
            <th class="col3 tablesorter-header">
                <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Location</div>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="job-posts-body" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col1">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2 class="job-title">Engineer-Customer Support</h2>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col2"><a href="#"><span class="job-category">Engineering - Software</span></a></td>
            <td class="col3"><a href="#"><span class="job-location">New York, New York</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col1">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2 class="job-title">Engineer title 2</h2>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col2"><a href="#"><span class="job-category">Engineering - Hardware</span></a></td>
            <td class="col3"><a href="#"><span class="job-location">Los Angeles, California</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col1">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2 class="job-title">Sales Manager</h2>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col2"><a href="#"><span class="job-category">Sales</span></a></td>
            <td class="col3"><a href="#"><span class="job-location">Los Angeles, California</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col1">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2 class="job-title">Janitor</h2>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col2"><a href="#"><span class="job-category">Other</span></a></td>
            <td class="col3"><a href="#"><span class="job-location">Orlando, Flordia</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col1">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2 class="job-title">Tech Support Level 1</h2>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col2"><a href="#"><span class="job-category">Tech Support</span></a></td>
            <td class="col3"><a href="#"><span class="job-location">Cincinnati, Ohio</span></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr role="row">
            <td class="col1">
                <a href="#">
                    <h2 class="job-title">Tech Support Level 2</h2>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td class="col2"><a href="#"><span class="job-category">Tech Support</span></a></td>
            <td class="col3"><a href="#"><span class="job-location">Cincinnati, Ohio</span></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Question 1**

I want to improve the search input to use filter function and not be case senitive. Or whatever function makes the most sense.

It can search for the entire row, doesnt have to just be the title.

I'm currently filtering it with :contains and doesn't work great because it is case sensitive and it just seems like there should be a better route to take.

```
var input_val = '';
$('.search-keyword').on('keyup',function(){
    input_val = $(this).val();
    if(input_val.length >= 3){
        $('.job-posts-body tr').hide()
        $('.job-posts-body tr:contains("'+input_val+'")').show();
    }else{
        $('.job-posts-body tr').show()
    }
})
```

**Question 2**

filter table based on category using filter function or whatever makes sense.

Im using a multiple select 2. It returns an array of categories.

```
// select input for category    
$('.select-category').on('change',function(){
    console.log( $(this).val() );// array of categories
    // filter table with the above array for the category column
})

// select input for location
$('.select-location').on('change',function(){
    console.log( $(this).val() );// array of locations
    // filter table with the above array for the location column
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to Question 1 is contained (no  pun intended) in Chris Coyier's article at:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/
CAVEAT: Be sure to read the comments about overriding jQuery funcionality and creating a new selector (e.g. :Icontains).